# Jar file doesn't create excel file

Tags: java, jar

I have a problem with my jar file that should create an excel file. With I run my app from NetBeans it works fine, but when I run a jar file it doesn't show any exception (I catch all exceptions) and it just doesn't create excel file. 
Path is not a problem, I create my excel file on root.

Does anyone has an idea what could be?

Comment: *I catch all exceptions* : Do you log those exceptions too ? If yes, then share them .

Comment: Yes, i am printing all exceptions, jar doesn't show any

Comment: Probably your application doesn't find the excel-library. That what the exception should tell you. Just catching all exceptions without proper handling or logging is a very bad idea.

Comment: It was a problem with excel library I forgot to change my folder lib.
Thank you

Comment: @MarijaTodorović *I forgot to change my folder lib* What did you do to solve the problem? If possible, can you share the folder structure if you still have it.

Answer (score 0):

You should check access permissions to folders.
you may able to create the excel document when you're under Netbeans as you launched it as and administrator but is Java (JRE) has same permissions to the folder ? especially under Linux.

To test try sudo before command line or if you're under Windows try to launch the console as and administrator.

Comment: *To test try sudo before command line or if you're under Windows try to launch the console as and administrator.*  Can you share more information on how we can do this??